# Every countable closed set is of uniqueness

Tags: fourier-analysis, proof-explanation, fourier-series, transfinite-induction

I am following the proof of Cantor's theorem that every countable closed set is of uniqueness as given in Kechris' notes (available [here](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~kechris/papers/uniqueness.pdf), thm. 4.2, proof on p. 12).

My doubts are the following: how can he claim that the translation of a set of uniqueness is still of uniqueness? I mean, that is intuitively clear, but I don't see how can he claim that with the tools he developed up to that point. Moreover (and maybe more importantly) where does the assumption that $0\notin E$ comes into play? Why doesn't the same proof work if we assume that $0\in E$?